# Starred list in chat isn't scrollable

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars

Before clicking on "show 7 more":

[image]

After:

[image]

I know this is probably really minor, but as you can tell, the scrollbar is set down to the very bottom, yet there's no option to view down the other 7 starred messages. In fact, you can only see the same ones available before, and there's no way to view it in the same pane (without clicking on "show all 37083" and going to a new tab)

Comment: +1 It's normal that you don't get to scroll the star list, but it's weird that there'd be a "show X more" option that gives you items you can't see at that point anyway.